# Best way to upgrade existing deployments to the latest version

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, deployment, mercurial

I need to automate the process of upgrading the existing deployments of an application to the latest stable revision of the application. I currently have a plan to do this by storing each change inside an upgrade application and then upgrading from a version to each new version in sequence until I arrive at the latest version. I would force all of my developers to add the upgrade code to the upgrade application each time we have a new stable release. This wouldn't be that complicated except for we have a MySQL database where the schema sometimes changes and we add stored procedures. Also, we usually have to swap out some binaries. The application consists of a Web Application and a Windows Service.

My question is, is there an easier way to do this? It seems to me that I should be able to package a Mercurial repository and automate pushing the changes to the deployed application. I am using C#.NET, MySQL, and ASP.NET for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to have one of my programmers write a really smart db script that doesn't need to store sequential changes. It will just compare the current schema to the new one and make the changes. That way, I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why you'd need to have a sequential upgrade of your schema changes but why would you do the same with your application instead of a one-step upgrade? Anyway, there are deployment tools like KwateeSDCM or Capistrano that can automate the deployment to dev/qa/production servers. KwateeSDCM keeps an MD5 hash of every file which allows it to to differential upgrades which is nice when you have large applications with frequent upgrades that impact only small files so it ends up doing pretty much what you want.

Comment: Well, I guess my thought is that since I have to step sequentially through each db revision (i.e. if I added a column in one revision but deleted another in a different revision this is the only way to catch it) each version of the program may or may not be affected by the schema change. Also, unless I just replaced every file on the upgrade, different files where changed at each revision. Also, there are xml files which have configuration information that I can't loose.

Comment: It also needs to be sequential in that we want all deployments, which might have different versions to be upgraded by the same application.